# Como puedo utilizar dos rangos de fechas en Java para buscar usuarios de na semana o de un mes

Tags: java, java-swing

como puedo utilizar dos rangos de fechas para buscar usuarios que trabajaron ya sea en una semana o en un mes, hasta el momento lo que tengo es que me buscas los usuarios y los servicios que realizaron pero los muestra de todas fechas, lo que yo quiero es poner dos JDateChooser y seleccionar una fecha digamos de 2020/05/01 al 2020/05/08.

```
public void consultarDatos(){
    String[] titulos = {"ACOMODADOR", "SERVICIOS POR SEMANA"};
      String[] datos = new String[2];

   String sql = "SELECT altavehiculos.acomodador As Acomodador, COUNT(*) As servicios "
           + "FROM altavehiculos  "
           +"WHERE fecha_hora_entrada BETWEEN ? AND ? "
           + "GROUP BY acomodador";



   model = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

      conectarBD conec = new conectarBD();
      Connection cn = conec.conexion();
      try {
          PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
          ps.setString(1, ((JTextField) JDateinicio.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
          ps.setString(2, ((JTextField) JDatefinal.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
          ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

          while (rs.next()) {
              datos[0] = rs.getString("acomodador");
              datos[1] = rs.getString("servicios");



           model.addRow(datos);

          }

          JTEmpleado.setModel(model);
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
      }
```

}

Comment: Ese filtro tienes que expresarlo en la consulta SQL, mediante `BETWEEN`. Te recomendaría además que usas `PreparedStatement` para este caso, evitando así ataques de Inyección SQL.

Comment: de esta manera podria ser  WHERE fecha_hora_entrada BETWEEN 'YYY-MM-dd ' AND 'YYYY-MM-dd'

Comment: Correcto. Y recogerías ambas fechas de un campo de texto o de donde sea. Pero OJO, usa consultas preparadas (mediante `PreparedStatement`) para evitar Inyección SQL. Es más seguro y además más fácil y más rápido a nivel de base de datos.

Comment: dentro del try catch lo tengo asi ya con el PreparedStatement

Comment: ps.setString(1, ((JTextField) JDateinicio.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
              ps.setString(2, ((JTextField) JDatefinal.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

Comment: No, `Statement` no es lo mismo que `PreparedStatement`, con el primero tendrías que pasar los datos directamente en la consulta, y es ahí donde ocurre la inyección, mientras que con el segundo pasas los datos mediante métodos específicos (`set...`), neutralizando cualquier intento de inyección. Revisa la documentación al respecto.

Comment: OK, veo que tienes los métodos `set...` pero en tu código veo esto: `Statement st = cn.createStatement();` que no concuerda (como ya dije, para este caso tendrías que trabajar con `PreparedStatement` no con `Statement`), además, en la instrucción SQL tienes que poner marcadores. Sugiero que pulses en [edit]  y pongas el código actualizado. Y si tienes algún error lo indicas también.

Comment: Ya lo edite nomas no se si esta bien la sintaxis para pode ingresar las fechas.

Comment: En la consulta sólo van los marcadores, tendrías que ponerlo así: `WHERE fecha_hora_entrada BETWEEN ? AND ? `  no olvides poner el espacio final para que no cree una consulta errónea al concatenar la instrucción SQL.

Comment: Aque te refieres con el espacio

Comment: con `JDateChooser` te refieres a la librería JCalendar( https://github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar )?

Comment: Me refiero a que en la parte del `WHERE` debe haber un espacio al final, sino te va a quedar así: `?GROUP BY ...`, o sea, debes ponerlo de este modo: `+"WHERE fecha_hora_entrada BETWEEN ? AND ? "
           + "GROUP BY acomodador";` dejando un espacio después del último marcador para que quede así: ... `WHERE fecha_hora_entrada BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY acomodador`

Comment: Ya edite nuevo el codigo manda una excepción: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN ? AND ?  GROUP BY acomodador' at line 1

Comment: Revisa que los nombres de tabla/columnas son correctos en la consulta, de paso yo cambiaría esto `SELECT altavehiculos.acomodador` por esto `SELECT acomodador`, no tiene sentido usar la notación `tabla.columna` cuando solo interviene una tabla en la consulta. Otra cosa, debes usar `setDate` y convertir las cadenas a fechas de algún modo (supongo que la columna que usas en el criterio es de tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`)

Comment: Buen día , A. Cedano, ok modificare el código y comento como me fue.

Comment: Gracias amigo Cedano por el apoyo ya quedo mi codigo.